# Using multiple taxonomy vocabularies for views filters

Tags: 7, views

I need to display nodes in a view, based on a combination of multiple taxonomy terms, in multiple vocabularies.  For example, for car sales, one vocabulary lets the visitor select one or more colors, and another selects one or more model types.

I assume I can do this by exposing filters, but how do I group them as check boxes in a sidebar instead of on top of the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "Advanced" section of your view settings, select Yes for the "Exposed form in block" setting.

Then there will be a block available for your view, which you can assign using drupal core blocks, context, panels, etc.